# How to get a specific amount of data from a CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 CSV files with the exact same structure and fields - the only thing that changes is the data, I managed to concatenate both, but in order to create a report I would like to get the column "Auditor" and the column "Time to audit" and create a report containing the name of teh Auditor x Total of tickets he audited and how much time he took to audit the tickets in a structure like below

AUDITOR | QTTY TICKETS AUDITED | TIME TO AUDIT

I have tried something but couldn't figure how to apply what I want to

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arquivo_csv_1 = '28-Jun-2021-audit.csv'
arquivo_csv_2 = '21-Jun-2021-audit.csv'

df_audit1 = pd.read_csv(arquivo_csv_1)
df_audit2 = pd.read_csv(arquivo_csv_2)

df_audit = pd.concat([df_audit1, df_audit2])

tickets_auditados = df_audit['AUDITOR'].count()
tempo_medio = df_audit.groupby(['AUDITOR']).sum()


print('\nTotal de tickets auditados: {}'.format(tickets_auditados))
print('\nTICKETS AUDITADOS POR AGENTE\n')
print(tempo_medio)
```

Any help will be much appreciated :D

Comment: What about a csv sample?

Answer (score 0):

You could try out a pivot table:

```
pivot_audit = pd.pivot_table(
    df_audit, index=["Auditor"], values=["Number", "Time"], aggfunc=np.sum
)
pivot_audit = pd.DataFrame(pivot_audit .to_records())

for index, row in pivot_audit.iterrows():
    print(f"Auditor {row.Auditor} processed {row.Number} tickets in {row.Time} seconds")
```